# Getting error: **Enumeration yielded no results**

Tags: linq

I'm getting the error **Enumeration yielded no results** while doing:

```
IEnumerable<Proxy> pxys = this._ticket.AllProxies.Where(p => p.IfBusy.Equals(false));
```

Comment: What are you doing with the `pxys` after that? Could you post the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you would get that error message is one of 2 reasons, either `this._ticket.AllProxies` contains no items (e.g. it is an empty collection) or none of the proxies in the collection have a value of `false` for their `IfBusy` property.

Comment: If the situation were what you describe, then the result would be simply an empty collection, no exception.

Comment: It's not throwing an exception, that's the message shown in the debugger when you view the results of the linq query.

Comment: Ah, so it's not an *error message*. I think you should make that clear in your answer.